# Loops in python need to run the loop only once

Tags: python

```
j=range(1,6)
for i in j:
     if(i==3):
         print("this is for i=3")
     else:
         print("this is for" + str(i))
```

the output i am getting is

```
this is for1
this is for2
this is for i=3
this is for4
this is for5
```

I need the output

```
this is for1
this is for i=3
```

i want the else loop should only execute for once
I tried using break also if i use break the if loop is not executing

Comment: You need an additional variable. Use a boolan to check if you've already visited the else block.

Comment: Question title seems a bit misleading.

Comment: Thank you Mike for the suggestion could you help me with it ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `elif` or use a `boolean` object to only visit inside the block once as:

With `elif`:

```
j=range(1,6)
for i in j:
     if(i==3):
         print("this is for i=3")
     elif i == 1:
         print("this is for" + str(i))
     else:
        pass
```

With a boolean object:

```
once = False    # to make sure we only visit once
for i in j:
    if(i==3):
        print("this is for i=3")
    else:
        if not once:
            print("this is for" + str(i))
            once = True   # set it to true to avoid visiting here again
```

Comment: Boolan is worked for me . Thank you so much krishna 
I am trying from may days for this .

Comment: Glad to be of help, @Ishika!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will give you the result you want :

```
j=range(1,6)
k=0
for i in j:
     if(i==3):
         print("this is for i=3")
     else:
         if (k==0):
             print("this is for" + str(i))
             k=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the `else` bit done once, you just need to remember that fact and not do it again, something like:

```py
j = range(1,6)
else_not_done = True
for i in j:
     if i == 3:
         print("this is for i=3")
     else:
         if else_not_done:
             print("this is for" + str(i))
             else_not_done = False
```